# How to navigate between screen on React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on this app for my family and so far i got everything up and running, but now I'm facing this issue because I want to load another view with `onPress()`, but I can't figure what my error is.

This is my code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Text} from 'react-native-paper';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native-paper';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import {Button} from 'react-native-paper';

const LoginScreen = () => {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const onLogin = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', userId);
      setLoading(false);
      this.navigation.push('Call');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error', err);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.root}>
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>Enter your name</Text>
        <TextInput
          label="Name"
          onChangeText={text => setUserId(text)}
          mode="outlined"
          style={styles.input}
        />

        <Button
          mode="contained"
          onPress={onLogin}
          loading={loading}
          style={styles.btn}
          contentStyle={styles.btnContent}
          disabled={userId.length === 0}>
         Connect
        </Button>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  content: {
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginBottom: 10,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  input: {
    height: 60,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  btn: {
    height: 60,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  btnContent: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: 60,
  },
});
export default LoginScreen(props);
```

Basically, everytime I press the button, I want my function `onLogin()` to navigate to my other file and load, but this is What I get.

```
[Wed Jun 10 2020 19:32:41.934]  LOG      Error [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: props]
[Wed Jun 10 2020 19:32:42.951]  LOG      Error [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: props]
[Wed Jun 10 2020 19:32:46.182]  LOG      Error [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: props]
[Wed Jun 10 2020 19:32:46.517]  LOG      Error [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: props]
[Wed Jun 10 2020 19:32:46.820]  LOG      Error [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: props]
[Wed Jun 10 2020 19:32:47.733]  LOG      Error [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: props]
[Wed Jun 10 2020 19:32:48.500]  LOG      Error [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: props]
[Wed Jun 10 2020 19:33:02.840]  LOG      Error [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: props]
[Wed Jun 10 2020 19:33:05.786]  LOG      Error [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: props]
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or can anyone point me out on where to go with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `props` from the export. props will be passed automatically into the component by react. The issue here is that you are calling `LoginScreen` with props, and props doesn't actually exist outside of the scope of `LoginScreen`

So instead have `export default LoginScreen`

Additionally, add `props` to the function definition of `LoginScreen` so it becomes: `const LoginScreen = (props) => { ... }`

Then wherever you have the login screen instantiated use `<LoginScreen **ADD ANY PROPS YOU WANT TO ADD HERE** />`

Comment: It solved that error and I can see why it was like that, but now I got ```[Wed Jun 10 2020 20:42:22.712]  LOG      Error [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation')]```

What could it be?

Comment: Make sure you added props to the parameters list! i.e. `const LoginScreen = (props) => { ... }`.

Comment: Also given this error I assume that you're using react-navigation, make sure that your whole app is wrapped in a `<NavigationContainer>` component. You can also console log your props to ensure they are what you expect.